# High and unstable ping to router

Tags: wireless

my wifi adapter is rtl8811CU, yesterday i installed the drivers, and had a 50 mbps download speed. Now my download speed is 1 mbps and my upload speed is 19 mbps. My ping to local router is unstable.

```
   PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=129 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=3.28 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=2.95 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=2.60 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=4.22 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=3.47 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=29.8 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=37.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=278 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=212 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=1.89 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=4.57 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=101 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=18 ttl=64 time=3.44 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=19 ttl=64 time=9.43 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=20 ttl=64 time=3.51 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=21 ttl=64 time=2.91 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=24 ttl=64 time=309 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=25 ttl=64 time=575 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=27 ttl=64 time=18.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=28 ttl=64 time=5.81 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=33 ttl=64 time=4.11 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=34 ttl=64 time=6.60 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
35 packets transmitted, 23 received, 34.2857% packet loss, time 276ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.885/76.030/574.890/139.144 ms
```

i tried the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858265/extremely-high-ping-to-local-router-over-wifi), but it didnt work.
I use 5ghz wifi.
lshw:

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3:2
       logical name: wlx1cbfce34dbc1
       serial: 1c:bf:ce:34:db:c1
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl88x2bu ip=192.168.1.13 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11AC
```

iwconfig:

```
wlx1cbfce34dbc1  IEEE 802.11AC  ESSID:"[name] 5"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
         Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.5 GHz  Access Point: 3C:98:72:BE:26:AD   
         Bit Rate:867 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
         Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
         Power Management:off
         Link Quality=38/100  Signal level=-74 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
         Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
         Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 59)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 7
01:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43d5 (rev 01)
01:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c8 (rev 01)
01:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c6 (rev 01)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
02:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
02:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X] (rev c7)
06:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 580]
07:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 145a
07:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Platform Security Processor
07:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] USB 3.0 Host controller
08:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1455
08:00.2 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
08:00.3 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 062a:5918 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1a2c:0044 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2357:0109 TP-Link TL WN823N RTL8192EU
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

[my driver](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959).
[dmesg](https://pastebin.com/r8f9MWUM).
ip route:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlx1cbfce34dbc1 proto dhcp metric 600 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlx1cbfce34dbc1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.12 metric 600
```

ifconfig:

```
enp4s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b4:2e:99:47:03:20  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 247595  bytes 14154180 (14.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 247595  bytes 14154180 (14.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx1cbfce34dbc1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.12  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::8b14:aaff:4cad:534d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 1c:bf:ce:34:db:c1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5070503  bytes 6864884854 (6.8 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 83996  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2038836  bytes 234664726 (234.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I hope i provided enough information.

Comment: Please Edit your question to add info from `ip route`, and check your MTU with `sudo ifconfig`.

Comment: done. my MTU is 1500, and i never touched it, should i change it?

Comment: WiFi MTU should be 1482. The MTU setting is applied ONLY when the interface comes up, so you'll hve to yo-yo it to really make the change.

Comment: i updated my mtu to 1482, but the problem is still there